# Do processors have optimizations and architecture preferences targeted firstly or mainly to C/C++ languages?

Tags: c, performance, optimization, cpu, cpu-architecture

I have read an article [C Is Not a Low-level Language](https://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=3212479), where is such paragraph:

> Unfortunately, simple translation providing fast code is not true for
> C. **In spite of the heroic efforts that processor architects invest in
> trying to design chips that can run C code fast**, the levels of
> performance expected by C programmers are achieved only as a result of
> incredibly complex compiler transforms. The Clang compiler, including
> the relevant parts of LLVM, is around 2 million lines of code. Even
> just counting the analysis and transform passes required to make C run
> quickly adds up to almost 200,000 lines (excluding comments and blank
> lines).

What does a bold sentence mean? Does it mean that manufacturers design processors with some optimizations and architecture decisions targeted firstly or even specifically to C (C++) code? Or it just means that they are trying to design processors that executes any code faster, including the code written in C language?

If some preferences to C exists, what are they?

My couple of thoughts:

- a branch prediction algorithm tuned in to patterns happening mainly in C code.
- instructions which are useful and used in C but aren't useful in other languages. Otherwise other languages (compilers) will use them too.

I knows about language specific processors like **Jazelle** or **Lisp machine** for Java and Lisp respectively, but similar technologies can't be applied to C, because there are no bytecode.

Comment: Re: "because there are no bytecode" -- there's no reason C can't be compiled to bytecode with whatever advantage that supposedly gives.

Comment: @PeteBecker With clang, source code -> LLVM bytecode -> machine code, I believe.

Comment: As I understand it, C was designed to be low enough to have almost assembler-like performance but to be 'portable' across architectures. Whether one calls it 'high' or 'low' level depends on your point of view. If you're used to VHDL then assembler might seem 'high' to you. Compiler magic definitely plays a part but processors don't 'run C', C tends to compile to more concise binaries as compared to 'higher' level languages which tend to have more bloat. I don't know what you're asking really.

Comment: @SimonGoater The quoted paragraph has a sentence highlighted by bold font. This sentence sounds like processors have predisposition to C language. Also, in article have been said, that processors are trying to be similar to a C abstract machine.

Comment: Why not ask the author? David.Chisnall AT cl.cam.ac.uk

Comment: I'd say byte addressing is mainly driven by the need to support C.

Answer (score 4):

Processors don't necessarily have optimizations targeted at C, but they do provide features to make C (and other procedural languages in general) map more cleanly to the platform.

Take cache-coherency in a multi-threaded environment as an example.  From a C perspective, a global variable shared by two threads should look the same to both threads.  If one thread writes to it the other should be able to see those modifications.  But in a multi-core CPU with independent caches, that takes extra effort to support.  Core 1 has to be able to detect that core 2 is accessing an address it has modified in cache and flush that out to memory (or somehow share it directly to core 2's cache).

That's essentially the thesis of that entire article.  C's abstract machine model doesn't necessarily map cleanly to real modern high-performance processors like it did to the (by comparison extremely simple) PDP-11, and CPUs and compilers have to take great pains to paper over those differences.

Comment: C, or any other language for that matter, can't do things that the instruction set can't do. The memory management system takes care of the cache hierarchy and is mostly part of the hardware. Apart from prefeching, I'm not aware of any way any a computer program can tell the CPU how to handle memory caching. This isn't an issue purely with C, but all programming languages. Am I wrong?

Comment: @SimonGoater You're correct, but people discuss mainly C in this sort of context because C is considered to by "close to the metal".  It's just important to remember that C is only "close to the metal" because the metal has had to mold itself around C, and sometimes the mold doesn't fit perfectly.

Comment: @SimonGoater: Right, the article is just using C as a protypical example of a "low level" language with a serial sequential model of execution.  It all applies equally to similar languages like Pascal and Rust.  (Although languages that let you operate on all elements of an array without as much of a manual loop over it do make it different for some of their auto-vectorization points).  For the cache stuff specifically, yeah even things like Matlab/Octave and R are essentially in the same boat; almost all language models are built around coherent caches, not explicit message-passing like MPI.

Answer (score 4):

The "heroic efforts" of the processor architects is largely referring to the design of cache and memory subsystems on the CPUs.

For a very long time now, the instruction executions circuits inside the CPUs have been far, far quicker than the electronics that looks after fetching/writing data from/to memory, largely because the technologies we have for RAM chips is hasn't really got better. Where the cores have speeded up the memory hasn't, and so the cache and memory subsystem has to get ever more elaborate in order to be able to pre-fetch data and move it towards the execution circuits ahead of time. Needless to say, this doesn't always pan out well.

It's also partly because of the physical distance between the CPU and RAM chips. Though only a few inches (if that) of track on a motherboard, that distance is significant; the speed of a signal down the track is about 1ns every 8 inches. For signals clocked in the GHz range (1 cycle << 1ns), a short track is a long way. This is partly why Apple have gone down the route of putting RAM onto the same package as the CPU in the home-grown M1 silicon.

Back to caches - the likes of Intel (and AMD, ARM) have strived to make CPUs that have good, general purpose performance, so that they run pretty much any code well. Modern compilers help a lot - if they know what the cache in the CPU is likely to do in any particular circumstance, the compilers can arrange code to fit in with what the hardware is likely to do.

A reasonable question then is, is that effective? Well, yes and no. Yes, because compiled code does run quite well, but no for a couple of reasons. The first is that ultimate performance for any given algorightm is rarely reached by the compiler / CPU, and secondly all this complexity makes it nigh on impossible for a good programmer to do their own optimisation.

Some CPUs help out the hero-programmer here. PowerPC (at least some variants) has instructions where the programmer can give the cache system a hint that the programme will shortly need data from such-and-such a location in RAM. The CPU uses that instruction to pre-load the L1 cache with that data, so that when the program actually starts to perform operations on data at that address it's already in cache.

The IBM Cell processor took this to a whole new level. The SPE math cores (there were 8 of them) had no cache, and no way of addressing data in CPU RAM at all. What there was instead was 256K of static RAM per core into which all code and data had to fit, and a way for code to push code and data in and out of that static RAM very quickly (256Gbyte/sec at the time, which was very very quick). The developer was completely on their own; they had to write code to load code and data into a core, get that executed, and then write more code to get the results out to wherever. This was actually pretty liberating; instead of having a cache and memory subsystem trying to automatically deliver data to executions cores, get in the way or (worse) just hide inefficiencies from you, one had the freedom to break down an algorigthm into core-sized lumps knowing that if it fitted, it'd be very quick, or knowing for sure it didn't fit.

**Miles Budnek**'s answer addresses the issues that arise from multi-core CPUs with a cache-coherency and a Symetric Multi Processing (SMP) environment. It's even harder for the cache designer to get it right if there's multuple cores that might very well start tampering with a value. The difficulties involved has lead to vulnerabilities like Meltdown and Spectre.

SMP could be said to be an "optimisation" put into CPUs by designers to aid the C (or other) developer in transitioning code from single to multiple thread. It's an attractive thought - in the way that a single thread programme can see all of it's data merely by addressing it, why not extend the same visibility of data to all threads in the programme?

Turns out that this is what makes it very difficult to design modern CPUs. However the reasons why the industry went this way are plain enough - the smallest possible delta between single and multicore CPUs was going to be the least troublesome for the existing software community to adopt. That's perfectly reasonable.

But it is running out of steam, fast. A better approach (if the goal is the outright pursuit of performance) would be to go back to the old Transputer architectures from Inmos from the 1980s, early 1990s. In such architectures, data held by one core could only be processed by another if the software was written to explicitly transfer the data. Sounds familiar? Yes - Cell process was a bit like that.

Interestingly, languages such as Rust, Go, Erlang have all implemented Communicating Sequential Processes as a parallel processing paradigm. The irony is that, these days, CSP has to be implemented on top of a SMP environment, which is itself an artificial construct brought about by the interconnect between CPUs, cores and memory (e.g. QPI, Hypertransport). Basically, if the whole software world got fully comfortable with CSP then CPU designers wouldn't have to design cache-coherency into their multi-core CPUs. Rust in particular is very well suited, as it already has a strong concept of data ownership in its syntax (which could be leveraged to shovel data around between cores automatically).

Comment: This is ultimately very reminiscent of the transition between graphics APIs like OpenGL and D3D11 to Metal, Vulkan, and D3D12. The underlying model of the older APIs had grown so distinct from the underlying hardware that Herculean efforts needed to be made by both drivers and programmers just to keep performance going. So they eventually had to just chuck everything out and start over with a fundamentally different paradigm.

Comment: Many architectures have software-prefetch instructions, including x86.  On modern x86 the hardware prefetchers are pretty good so you often don't have much if anything to gain from SW prefetch, though, except in cases like binary search where future accesses are to one of a set of possible addresses, but aren't sequential.  On hardware without aggressive HW prefetch, it was more important to use SW prefetch.  (e.g. Pentium 4 especially.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I was fairly sure of that but I was certain of only PowerPC :-) Always thought that fitting a CPU with pre-fetch instructions was a bit like admitting that the devs would ultimately be better off managing data flows from RAM <-> cache <-> core themselves, but not being able to go whole way in that direction for (pretty sound) commercial reasons. It was an eye-opener when IBM did the Cell processor! From what I hear the games developers for PS3 took a while to get used to it but once mastered could achieve very impressive results (by which time PS4 came along...).

Answer (score 1):

The article referred to by the OP seems to me to have it in for C for some reason. There were so many points in it I felt triggered by, but I don't want to go addressing each one point by point. Maybe there is some bias or special interest that has not been declared. As a C programmer, with a particular interest in writing high performance programs, I thought I'd give my two cents on some of the issues raised. Hopefully, this might be of interest to others in the industry with or without a programming background.

From my point of view, the strengths of C are mainly as follows....

1. C allows you to do things you just can't do in 'higher level' languages.
2. A well written C (see weakness no.1) program is hard to beat on performance on the same hardware, written in another language.
3. C is comfortable handling binary data allowing for memory conservation.
4. C is well established with lots of libraries and programmers.
5. Objects in memory can be made easy to process from anywhere in the program by using pointers so the data itself doesn't need to be passed around.
6. Multi-threaded and multi-process programs are quite easy to implement.
7. It has Read-Write shared memory between threads (and processes with some fancy low-level stuff?)
8. Assembly can be inlined where needed (though it's not C then I know!).

... and main weaknesses...

1. Utilising SIMD capabilities is not possible in standard C, and difficult to implement in a portable way with intrinsics.
2. It takes a lot of code to do simple things for which there are no library functions.
3. Buffer overflow potential is easily missed, even for experienced programmers.
4. C pointers can be confusing.

The C programming language has a special place in the evolution of programming languages and I for one, would welcome a replacement that is a better fit to what is possible with modern hardware if it doesn't tie the hands of the programmer and offers better security and performance. From the article,...

'A processor designed purely for speed, not for a compromise between speed and C support, would likely support large numbers of threads, have wide vector units, and have a much simpler memory model. Running C code on such a system would be problematic, so, given the large amount of legacy C code in the world, it would not likely be a commercial success.'

Such things exist already, GPUs! Modern CPUs are much more like GPUs than they used to be now core counts can be 100+. I have used OpenCL C to write programs with amazing computational performance but they can't do everything well. Some applications can not be efficiently parallelised, if at all. OpenCL C program performance can become terrible when there is even a small amount of branching. Also, it is so much easier to exhause your memory bandwidth and fast cache when running many threads that it might be judged not worth the added complexity over a good single threaded implementation.

In OpenCL C, the programmer has somewhat more control of where data is stored in memory which can definately aid performance. Maybe it's a costly mistake to try to make programming languages too hardware independent. Might it be better to review some (LLVM like) intermediate standard, like in OpenCL C, where one can define 'private', 'local' and 'constant' memory objects to get performance improvements over 'global' memory objects. Such a standard wouldn't need to be tied to an instruction set. As a programmer, I welcome fast CPU instructions but it would be nice if they could be much more easily utilised in portable code AND compilable to portable binaries. Maybe this is something compiler writers could look into along with using SIMD vector registers rather than memory for pushing and popping. As I see it, there are four levels of portability.

1. Hardware independent source code to run on any hardware conforming to the intermediate standard. The burden is on the compiler to create binaries that will run correctly and efficiently on any hardware conforming to the intermediate standard.
2. Hardware independent source code to run on any hardware conforming to the intermediate standard. The burden is on the host compiler to create binaries that will run on the host's  hardware configuration conforming to the intermediate standard, but may not run on other hardware conforming to the same.
3. Hardware dependent source code where the logical execution path through the source depends on the architecture of the hardware on which it is run. Programs need to 'query' the hardware configuration.
4. Hardware specific source code.

In a fantasy world where one can just imagine new standards, hardware, and programming languages, one could choose which level of portablity to aim for. I think that C was supposed to be hardware independent, but it isn't really if you want to get the best performance out of your hardware. OpenCL C tries also, but doesn't quite make it, though with run-time kernel compilation it does a pretty good job. The host program has the same issues though as any other. I don't think there are any 'Level 1' portable languages currently.

Sorry my response is a bit rambling. It's unfortunate that it's difficult to have an objective constructive discussion about the pros and cons of different ideas about future changes in software and hardware. Personally, I think FPGAs have huge potential but are still a long way from where they would need to be to go mainstream. Any new computing language will probably become out of date when hardware changes occur and software trends change. It's remarkable that C still occupies such a prominent space. In another 10 or 20 years time, C will probably still be going strong. How many other modern languages will still be commonplace then?

Comment: I think the author of that article is an LLVM developer, and most of their points apply to other low-level languages where you'd manually loop over arrays instead of telling the compiler what you want to happen to every array element.  They're not saying we shouldn't use C, just that making it as good as it is requires a *lot* of work by compilers.  And that giving the illusion of a fast core running instructions one at a time in program order is increasingly difficult for CPU architects, not scaling well and costing a lot of power.

Comment: Although C does have a lot of weird warts, made worse by optimizing compilers being aggressive about UB to extract more performance.  Rust is designed much better in this respect with its integer overflow rules, and has builtins for things CPUs can do like bit-scan and popcount that ISO C++ only added in C++20 and ISO C still doesn't have.  I'm less optimistic about highly parallel languages being able to solve every kind of problem efficiently, but yeah the way programs are written makes it hard not to bake in more serialization than necessary, for lack of a way to expose it to the HW.

Comment: So basically, the author isn't saying some other language would clearly be better right now, for existing CPUs.  They're saying that a revolution in CPU design would require a major change in programming, away from a C-like model of serial execution of a few threads.  (But also that C specifically is showing its age with which things are undefined behaviour.)  As someone who understands modern CPU architecture and some about how compilers compile C to asm, and the challenges of getting them to make efficient asm, I found the article very insightful.

Comment: @Peter Cordes Maybe people expect too much from compilers if they expect a compiler produce asm that executes a program in the fastest way a CPU can achieve the end result, rather than just do as it is told. I've found C with OpenCL C to be a very powerful combination though it's fair to say it isn't easy to program.

Comment: The point of the article is that it would be even better if people didn't have to know a ton about CPUs to write efficient programs for them.  In the C abstract language model, if you assume every operation takes about the same time, that works for PDP-11 but not for Skylake.  The ideal is a way for humans to naturally express programs without having to spend a lot of time micro-optimizing them, instead if there were a way to convey enough info to compilers for them to be able to make the implementation-detail decisions that led to good performance.

Comment: Even getting 50% of the performance of a hand-tuned C / OpenMP or C+OpenCL program written by an expert would be pretty reasonable for a lot of users.  (Like folks who currently use Python + NumPY to glue together optimized building blocks, often with memory bottlenecks.)  And have way more value if it opened up the possibility of running on machines that didn't need high single-thread performance, because that's expensive in terms of power and die area for hardware.

Comment: It would that! There's a ton of performance that is typically present but not utilised. Relying on compiler magic to make a program run fast could be a fickle thing which gets lost after just a trivial program alteration. Not good if you need that high performance. In that case, it's better to hand-code it. Personally, I like computers to do what I tell them to, but not try to be too clever :)

Comment: Yeah, same, I find computers and computing inherently interesting, so it's fun to micro-optimize code, and vectorize it with SIMD.  And generally think about how a superscalar out-of-order pipeline is going to execute it.  But a lot of research scientist just want to implement some math, and don't care how the computer does it, and don't know assembly language or want to look at the compiler-generated asm to see if it's efficient.  C is not a great language for that use-case and attitude.

Comment: Some of the biggest deficiencies in current C compilers (except ICC) is their inability to auto-vectorize loops whose trip-count can't be calculated before the first iteration.  That makes `memcmp` and `strlen` into opaque building blocks that [magically run faster than anything you can do](//stackoverflow.com/a/49991933) in ISO C or [Rust](//stackoverflow.com/a/73119184), and memcmp annoyingly only returns one value, and it isn't the position of the mismatch.  So if you want to do something vectorizable until a mismatch or terminator, you're screwed unless you do 2 passes, one for strlen.

Comment: @PeterCordes ">to glue together optimized building blocks, often with memory bottlenecks". I wonder if you've ever come across the VSIPL library? It's C, but it has the interesting feature of "application memory" and "library memory" (can't remember the exact words). Basically, you have to transfer data from application into library space to perform maths operations. Left in "library space", the data was opaque but more operations could be performed, and you could get the result vector back to application space at the end. I found it an interesting way to ward off memory inefficiencies!

Comment: @bazza: I haven't; does it defer actual computation until you request a copy back to application memory, and then cache-block for you?  Or JIT optimized loops that do multiple steps at once?  Or does it just use that "library memory" concept to maybe let it offload to GPUs, or keep data in different formats (like complex numbers as two arrays of real and imag part separately, instead of inconveniently interleaved).  Interesting idea either way, though, of course coming with tradeoffs of potential extra copying.

Comment: @PeterCordes it's strictly for CPUs, you can get versions for AVX, SSE, Altivec, etc. The idea is that the internal representation of data is suited to the CPU architecture, so that when you ask it fo FFT a vector that happens ASAP. But the result vector is still in the ideal representation for another op (like, magnitude). There's no JITing or cleverness like that. The "trick" was understanding what it's internal representation was, so that the "admit to library space" was zero effort. So, I'd build the electronics (ADC system) to output data in the right shape to begin with, save a step.

Comment: @PeterCordes but my favourite has been Mercury's SAL. You have to properly align and represent data (e.g. interleave or splt complext vectors), but the fastest DSP primitives per CPU I've ever seen. They have some very clever developers. Both libraries cost money, but for systems that need it it's worthwhile. Links FYI, https://www.omg.org/spec/VSIPL/1.5/About-VSIPL/, https://nasoftware.co.uk/index.php/library-products/vsipl, https://www.mrcy.com/products/development-software-tools/multicore-plus-mathpack-es-accessory. Both are sort of third party Intel MKL, but platform portable.